# Sketch and find the differential equation of all lines through the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, curves

We've just finished discussing about elimination of arbitrary constants, so I'm confused on how to solve and sketch this type of problem, I was told that the answer in this problem is $xy'-y=0$ but wait, how did that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $y=cx $ is a solution for every $c $, so allowing $c $ to be arbitrary, we can get any line through the origin.

Comment: okay... but how will i get $xy'-y=0$?

Comment: Every line through the origin has the form $y=cx$, so $y'=c$. It is easy to observe that $xy'=cx=y$, so $xy'-y=0$.